# accessing JSON field from dictionary webapi using Python

Tags: python, json, api

I need to access the definition term of this dictionary webapi, however I get an error:

"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

I'm using this webapi to access the 'dt' term from the tree:

https://www.dictionaryapi.com/products/json#sec-2.def

I've tried several ways of accessing strictly the text of the definition, but I never get strictly the definition

```
def main():
    key = "a key I use"
    word = "school"
    URL = "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/sd2/json/school?key=a key I use"
    PARAMS = {'word': word,'key': key}
    r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS) 
    definitions = []


    if r.status_code == 200:
        print('Definition found')
        r.encoding = 'utf-8'
        data = r.json()
        #print(r.content)
         print(data[0]['def']['sseq']['dt'][0])
```

so the last line, where I do the print returns to me:

```
Definition found
[['sense', {'sn': '1', 'dt': [['text', '{bc}a place for teaching and learning']]
}]]
```

but I can't seem to get the right sauce to get dt only

to be clear, I just want the words:

"a place for teaching and learning"

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: I updated it with what I'm getting for using: 
print(data[0]['def'][0]['sseq'][0])

Comment: this `data[0][1]['dt'][0][1]` gives me `{bc}a place for teaching and learning`

Comment: Why not just data[0][1]['dt'][0][1].split('{')[1]

Comment: That's odd, I get a key error:
"  File "Main.py", line 26, in main
    print(data[0][1]['dt'][0][1])
KeyError: 1"